# Error with gzip while used along with tar

Tags: tar, gzip

I am new to ubuntu. I have an error when using tar function along with gzip.
I usee the following code :

```
find -type d -name 'doc*' | tar -czvf /path/where/gz/file/is/stored/file.tar.gz -T-
```

But the process begins, starts zipping and it is interupted in between showing this:

```
gzip: short write 
tar: write error: Broken pipe
```

and creates a empty tar.gz. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Does it happen with other compression algorithms, e.g. `bzip2`: `tar -cj` or `xz`: `tar -cJ`?

Comment: yes, it happens -cj .

Comment: Does `find -type d -name 'doc*' -exec tar -cvzf file.tar.gz {} +` work?

Comment: i would like to clarify, if   the command has to be like this :  find -type d -name 'doc*' -exec tar  -cvzf /path/to file.tar.gz { } +

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -zcf /path/to/be/stored/file.tar.gz *
```

This worked. But you have to be in the particular folder of the files to be gzipped

Answer (score -1):

You're assuming that `tar` accepts a list of files to save from `STDIN`. It does not. See `man tar` and `info tar`.

A better way is, if your list of directories isn't too long, through command substitution:

```
tar -czvf /path/where/gz/file/is/stored/file.tar.gz \
    $( find . -type d -name 'doc*' -print)
```

Comment: It does, `-T-` is exactly for that.

Comment: using only tar was working well (but i still had doubling the size of the directory) though i got a tar file.